# how to make an installer with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have an inventory system and an export of a SQL Server database and I want to make an installer of it. But the problem is how can I install an SQL Server database? Can I join it in the installer maker in visual studio or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Visual Studio installer, but [you can in WiX](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql/creating-a-database).

Answer (score 0):

The solution we use involves importing the SQL database into Sql Server Data Tools (SSDT):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

We then use the DACPAC functionality of SSDT to build database pacakges which can either be deployed using the SQL UI or a powershell script, here is a rudimentary script we use:

```
cls

#get current folder
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path

#path to dac processing executables
$sqlPackagePath = “C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe”

## detect the publish file and detect the dacpac
$DacpacPath = $directorypath
$PublishProfile = $directorypath

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $directorypath)
{
    if ($file.Name.Contains("ssdt.dacpac"))
    {
        $DacpacPath = $file.Name

    } elseif ($file.Name.Contains(".publish.xml"))
    {
        $PublishProfile = $file.Name
    }
}

# execute the command to deploy the database
& $sqlPackagePath -Action:Publish -Profile:$PublishProfile -SourceFile:$DacpacPath | Out-File dacpac.log
```